# Why do combobox items take the whole screen if added dynamically but only the cbx's width when set in the XAML?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, combobox, windows-phone

I just don't understand why, technically there's no extra style set anywhere else. If I add them in the XAML file, I do see the dropdown menu but otherwise, the comboxes I populate dynamically, fill up all the screen when expanded :(

I'm only setting the resources an array as my source

```
    comboPredict.ItemsSource = predValues;
    comboPredict.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Why dont you show your code (dynamically adding part)

Comment: Only setting the source in the code. Some hidden format feature is also needed?

Answer (score 0):

So after reading it right...

The WPF ComboBox will set automatically to the widest element in the drop down list. The ComboBox uses a [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element to hold the list.

> A Popup is sized to its content by default.

In the MSDN ComboBox.ItemSource [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) you can read:

> When the ItemsSource property is set, the Items collection is made read-only and fixed-size.

So it will applying a RenderTransform on the Popup after setting the value.

It's also important to look at the parent of your control in the Visual-Tree of WPF.

---

**Work-Around 1:  Set the Width explicitly**

Which causing problems if you change Font-Size or Format or you're not sure how long the text of Item will be.

**Work-Around 2:  [Pavel's Solution](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2010/08/31/wpf-auto-size-combobox/)**

> This is not the “WPF way”